# How to tune a query that mutates a large portion of a Neo4j graph?

Tags: neo4j

I have a graph in Neo4j (v2.2.3) that has 2,895,711 nodes. Of these nodes there are 1,522,166 nodes that are labelled as `Entity` nodes with properties named `transactionId` and `requestId`. Each of these properties contains a GUID string value. The properties are not indexed. The `Entity` label has an indexed property which is unique named `identifier`, also containing a GUID string.

I wish to change the names of the two existing properties to `updatedTransactionId` and `updatedRequestId`, respectively. And to introduce two new properties named `createdTransactionId` and `createdRequestId` which will be initialised to `-unknown-`, but will be set specifically for all future transactions.

I'm running into an *exponentially* slowing response to the various *cypher* queries (via the RESTful endpoint) I have tried to use to perform this update. In working on the query I have used the `PROFILE` directive to examine the plan for each of the queries in attempt to reduced (eliminate) as many *scans* from the *plan* as possible.

The following query, performed in batches is my most recent attempt to achieve the result described above:

```
MATCH (e:Entity)
 WITH id(e) AS neoId, e.identifier AS identifier ORDER BY neoId SKIP 0 LIMIT 100000
 MATCH (n:Entity) WHERE n.identifier = identifier
  SET n.updatedRequestId = n.requestId,
      n.updatedTransactionId = n.transactionId,
      n.createdRequestId = '-unknown-',
      n.createdTransactionId ='-unknown-'
  REMOVE n.requestId, n.transactionId
 RETURN count(n)
```

Where the `SKIP` amount is incremented for each batch, running over 16 batches.

What I find is that the execution eventually gets exponentially slower as the batches are processed. For example, the first ten batches have taken the following elapsed processing times (minutes:seconds.decimalSeconds) per batch, in order: `00:17.0`, `00:09.6`, `00:10.1`, `00:21.1`, `01:22.8`, `02:11.0`, `03:35.9`, `06:12.1`, `08:22.2`, and `11:59.8`.

Does anybody have an explanation for the exponential decrease in performance? And, more importantly, a recommendation for a *better* way to achieve the desired result as described above?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Each batch still touches all `Entity` nodes. The trick is to avoid a `SKIP` by having a criteria for the non-migrated nodes and limit those for a reasonable batch size. In your case this might be the existence of the `requestId` property.

```
MATCH (n:Entity) 
WHERE HAS(n.requestId)
WITH n LIMIT 100000
SET n.updatedRequestId = n.requestId,
  n.updatedTransactionId = n.transactionId,
  n.createdRequestId = '-unknown-',
  n.createdTransactionId ='-unknown-'
REMOVE n.requestId, n.transactionId
RETURN count(n)
```

You need to run this until `0` is returned.

Comment: Thank you for your reply; very much appreciated. I have already tried a similar approach first and found that I still ran into exponentially increasing batch execution times. In particular, it appears that the `has(n.requestId)` predicate does _not_ use the schema indexes (according to `PROFILE`) using node scanning instead, and takes longer to find the few remaining nodes as the batches proceed. I'll give your query a shot and report back. Thanks, again.

Comment: Did this ever work for you? I've got ~20 million nodes and the match is always scanning.

`match (e:Entity) where not has(e.code) with e limit 100 set e.key = e.callerKeyRef`